# how to make subonic convert a String to my custom Type

Tags: c#, subsonic, types

I tried to search for it on google but couldn't find the answer so i'll try it here.
I am using Subonic and am trying to fill an object by using:

```
Model.Object o = new Select()
            .From<Object>()
            .Where("Id")
            .IsEqualTo(id)
            .ExecuteSingle<Model.Object>();
```

When doing so i get the error:
*Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'CustomType'*
One of the properties is stored in the database as varchar. In the Model.object this property is defined as CustomType. I already added an implicit operator to this type as folows:

```
public static implicit operator CustomType(String value)
    {
        return new CustomType(value);
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here? or am I missing something? any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing your own [TypeConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.aspx) so that it will be possible to recreate your `Model.Object` from string representation.

**EDIT**. After digging through SubSonic code I found out that this won't help (see [this](http://code.google.com/p/subsonicproject/source/browse/trunk/SubSonic/SqlQuery/SqlQuery.cs), `BuildTypedResult<T>`). Try implementing `IBaseRecord` if you like to, and implement `Load()` method.

Comment: I tried but with no succes. breakpoints in the converter class are not hit. i am clueless

Comment: Then i would be better of useing the generated class from SubSonic.

Answer (score 0):

If this were my project, I would probably build out a partial class for Model.Object, and then pop a factory method on there or maybe another constructor overload that takes a Reader. You can then use that reader to load the properties as needed, casting your CustomType.